# Connet Springboot with Firestore

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm learning Springboot framework and try to fetch data from firestore. I added the Google dependencies and follow google document to connect with the firebase project. However, when I tried to get data from firestore, I got error. Here is my code to fetch data from firestore

```
try {
        Firestore firestore = FirestoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
        System.out.println("Firestore: " + firestore);
        // Specify the collection you want to retrieve documents from
        String collectionName = "user";

        // Asynchronously retrieve all documents from the specified collection
        ApiFuture<QuerySnapshot> future = firestore.collection(collectionName).get();


        // Get the result of the future and retrieve the documents
        QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = future.get();
        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : querySnapshot) {
            // Document id (user id)
            String userId = document.getId();

            // Access other fields in the document
            Object userData = document.getData();

            System.out.println("User ID: " + userId);
            System.out.println("User Data: " + userData);
            System.out.println("-------------");
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I got error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreException.forIOException(FirestoreException.java:94)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreRpcFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:90)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreRpcFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:80)
at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getRpc(ServiceOptions.java:564)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions.getFirestoreRpc(FirestoreOptions.java:358)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreImpl.<init>(FirestoreImpl.java:79)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:71)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:64)
```

I tried to get data from the user collection. Here is how my firestore database looks. Have anyone know the solution? Thank you for reading my question!
[image]